# Algorithm to find Dominance Frontiers

Tags: compilers

The algorithm that is used by gcc and llvm is that of [Keith D. Cooper, Timothy J. Harvey, and Ken Kennedy](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~keith/EMBED/dom.pdf) (page 9).  We start with the *immediate dominators* of each control-flow graph node `B` already calculated and stored in `idom[B]`:

```
for each B in all basic blocks
    if size of Predecessors(B) >= 2
        for each P in Predecessors(B)
            runner = P
            while runner != idom[B]    # idom is the immediate dominator
                DF(runner) += B
                runner = idom[runner]
```

My question is about the `Predecessors` set. Do they refer to the direct predecessors ("fathers") of `B` or to all of them that lead to `B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Predecessors(B)` is just the set of direct predecessors of `B`.  The "fathers", not the more distant ancestors.

Dominance frontier nodes must be join points in the graph, and a node can only be a join point if it has more than one predecessor.